# How to push JSON data from postman to django framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am trying to figure out how to push raw JSON data in postman to my rest api using django and use that data to do some calculations.

I've tried several snippets of code but I can't figure it out

Here is my JSON :

```
{
   "Dependents": 1,
   "ApplicantIncome": 4583,
   "CoapplicantIncome": 1508,
   "LoanAmount": 128000,
   "Loan_Amount_Term": 360,
   "Credit_History": 1,
   "Gender_Female": 0,
   "Gender_Male": 1,
   "Married_No": 0,
   "Married_Yes": 1,
   "Education_Graduate": 1,
   "Education_Not Graduate": 0,
   "Self_Employed_No": 1,
   "Self_Employed_Yes": 0,
   "Property_Area_Rural": 1,
   "Property_Area_Semiurban": 0,
   "Property_Area_Urban": 0
 }
```

Here is the python code :

```py
@api_view(["POST"])
def ClientData(request):
    return Response(request.data)
```

The above code displays the JSON file in the postman response

Now I want to use the response above in another function that will do some calculations

```py
def NewData(request):
    data = ClientData(request)
    newsum=data['LoanAmount']*4
    print(newsum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method...

[image: postman image of input data]

In postman:

1. Select body
2. Click on raw
3. Make sure you selected JSON instead of text

client part is over, in server portion place the code in your view, remember in using django rest framework. Hope you will get an idea from my code

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
class TestAPIView(ListAPIView):

    def patch(self, request):
        data = self.request.data
        print("received data : ",data)

        someCalculation = data['LoanAmount']*4
        return Response({
           "status": True,
           "LoanAmount calculation": someCalculation,
            "data": data
        })
```

And here is the processed output:

[image: Response image]

Comment: Could you please explain the specific question you have more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize your data into a `Python` object, such us a dictionary (`dict`). Try checking **Django Rest Framework** documentation on *deserialization* to see the best practices for this is specific framework.

Currently you probably have an *String*-like object like `unicode` or `str` inside `request.data`; deserializing this data will convert it into a more functional *Hash*-like object like a `dict`.

Deserializing can be as simple as:

```
data = json.loads(request.data)
if data['key'] == something:
   . . .
```

But this is not practical in real work cases since the `Python`'s built in `json` module has some limitations, so again, refer to the frameworks deserializing methods.